# Can you get an emergency US transit visa?

Tags: usa, transit-visas, emergencies

We're in the UK, trying to get to Mexico City as soon as possible (bereavement).  There are a few flights from London transiting through the United States. However, my wife is Mexican and neither of us have a visa. Is it possible to get one issued under such circumstances?

Comment: Right now, Skyscanner says cheapest is with aerimexico, which is of course direct and so avoids any additional stress and bureaucracy. Why would you bother going via USA?

Comment: We were doing single journey searches since my wife would be staying there with her mother for a couple of months - the ones via the US were pretty fast and relatively cheap (£350 or so).

My wife didn't want me to pay, with minimal funds to buy a ticket.

Areomexico and the like were all £1000 single journey, however these were priced as returns, which wasn't to my knowledge. 

We went with KLM using a £200 voucher from Bristol (so saved her having no sleep on a coach to london).

Really appreciate everyones replies & help, was very helpful in this dificult situation - thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You would most likely have to get a C Visa in London.

https://uk.usembassy.gov/visas/transiting-the-united-states/

Processing times are 3-5 work days and it's not cheap either
https://uk.usembassy.gov/visas/transiting-the-united-states/processing-times-return-of-passport/

You may get lucky by showing up there in person and making a case for your special circumstance. However this is absolutely unpredictable. We had multiple experiences where consulate employees made up rules, timelines and requirements on the fly, regardless of what the official rules were, what your appointment letter stated, or what you had previously confirmed on the phone (multiple times!).

It would be far easier to fly directly to Mexico on British Airways or Aeromexico or route through Europe (Amsterdam, Paris, Frankfurt). I checked flight costs and they were all about the same, about $1500 round trip for departure tomorrow and return on the weekend. Another option could be Avianca through Bogota.